# algorithm: trying to get the index from array where |A[i] - i| <=c in log(N) with a divide and conquer algorithm

Tags: python, list, algorithm, sorting, divide-and-conquer

Input: a sorted array A (all elements are integer and distinct in increasing order) and c (integer)

Output: return a randomly selected index such that this index meet the requirement: `|A[i]-i| <= c`

It should run within O(logN) time in the worst case.

My original thought was to binary search index i, such that `A[i] = 0` or the closet to 0. Then this index divides the array into 2 parts.

The left part contains element < 0 and the right part contains element > 0.

For the right part, run a binary search-liked algorithm to check the mid-value and see whether `A[mid]-mid <=c`, if so, go to `[mid+1, end]`. However, I found this problem when I have the following example:

```
c=2
i     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
A[i] -5 -4  -1 0  1  5  8  9
```

`A[4]` does not meet `|A[4]-4| <=2` but it will be included in my algorithm. 
So I have no idea about this question at all now...

Comment: Imagine an array where the elements are `A[i]-i`. That array is guaranteed to be sorted ascending. So all you need to do is a binary search for the element closest to 0.

Comment: @user3386109. It's not sorted ascending. Theres an absolute value. If it was sorted, just take the first element. No searching necessary

Comment: @MadPhysicist For the given example, the virtual array for `A[i]-i` is `{-5,-5,-3,-3,-3,0,2,2}`. That seems sorted ascending to me. And it's true in general since OP specifies that the elements of `A` are distinct, which means that the elements of `A` must increase at least as fast as the indexes.

Comment: @גלעדברקן of course it is, but OP is asking about abs(A[i] - i). Otherwise this is literally trivial

Comment: @user3386109 but abs(A[i] - i) is 5 5 3 3 3 0 2 2. Good luck. -5 is either less than c or there is no solution. That's not the question though.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The element closest to zero is the only element in the virtual array that you care about, since that element has the best chance to be less than `c`.

Comment: @user3386109. Yes, that's what you need to find in the worst case. Best case you terminate early

Comment: @user3386109 can the near-zero element also help orient us to find the bounds of the interval from which to pick the random element?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yes, the near-zero element separates the array into two parts. You can then binary search the two parts to find the farthest from zero in each part that matches the condition.

Comment: @user3386109. I don't think that makes any sense. All keys are greater than zero and OP wants any index that satisfies the condition, not the closest element to c.

Comment: @גלעדברקן. If you can find the near zero element (a.k.a. the minimum), you don't need to search any further. It's random enough. I'm pretty sure OP meant arbitrary, as in any one will do, not actually random.

Comment: @user13571509. Did you mean arbitrary or random?

Comment: @user3386109. My mistake. Wrong ID, same final digits

Comment: @MadPhysicist don't know, OP was pretty explicit: "a randomly selected index such that this index meet the requirement: |A[i]-i| <= c" Deliberately choosing the near-zero element doesn't seem randomly selected to me.

Comment: @גלעדברקן. I was thinking the same, so I added a blurb to my answer about that until OP responds

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the data. It follows from `A` containing distinct sorted integers that for any pair of successive elements, `A[i] <= A[i + 1] - 1`.

The search keys for these elements are `A[i] - i` and `A[i + 1] - i - 1`. Subtracting `i` from both sides of the inequality shows that two successive keys are equal or increasing if positive, and equal or decreasing if negative.

If the problem did not ask for absolute values, it would be trivial to solve. You would just check the first element, and either it would meet there criterion, or no element would.

The absolute value means that your keys can be decreasing, increasing or steady. There decreasing region is always to the left of the minimum and the increasing region is to the right.

You can find the minimum in `log(N)` time with something similar to a binary search, but from both ends. The trick is to figure out which side of the midpoint to look at for the minimum.

Start with the two ends and the center of the array. Pick a midpoint for each half. If the halfway point is less than the center, the minimum is in that half: adjust the bounds to just that half and proceed. If not, that's your new endpoint for that half. You will do at most `2 * log(N/2) = O(log(N))` operations.

You can terminate early when your bounds all differ by at most 1, or you hit upon an element that satisfies the condition early.

If you truly do need a random element, rather than an arbitrary one, you will need to search for the bounds that satisfy the condition in each half. This will not add to the complexity since `O(4 log(N/2)) = O(log(N))`. Presumably picking a random number from that interval is `O(1)`.

I leave this last part as an exercise for the reader if necessary.